# Changing form to include a submit button for WCAG

Tags: html, accessibility, wcag, wcag2.0

I currently have a form like so:

```
<form action="#">
    <select {if $isPostRequest}disabled="disabled" {/if}size="1" name="locale" 
onchange="location.href={if $languageToggleNoUser}'{$currentUrl|escape}{if strstr($currentUrl, '?')}&amp;{else}?{/if}setLocale='+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value{else}('{url|escape:"javascript" page="user" op="setLocale" path="NEW_LOCALE" source=$smarty.server.REQUEST_URI}'.replace('NEW_LOCALE', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)){/if}" class="selectMenu">{html_options options=$languageToggleLocales selected=$currentLocale}</select>
</form>
```

It currently causes a WCAG 2.0 error, as [all forms need a submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H32.html).

I'm wondering how I could change this code to include a submit button. The code for the onchange option is quite convoluted, and I don't understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: WCAG 2.0 does not require to have a submit button. What you link to is a technique, which is informative (not normative), and it’s only one of possibly many ways to achieve the guideline [3.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change)

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, I should be looking at the success criteria rather than the technique tests. This form is a dropdown list of languages, when it is clicked the system loads a separate document with the different translation. This doesn't pass [3.2.2 On Input](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change), is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: It says "unless the user has been advised of the behavior before using the component" -- So if you describe what will happen, it should pass. Related technique: [G13: Describing what will happen before a change to a form control that causes a change of context to occur is made](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/G13).

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. Starting to get my head around WCAG now.

Answer (score 2):

WCAG 2.0 does not require to have a submit button. What you link to is a technique, which is informative (not normative), and it’s only one of possibly many ways to achieve the guideline [3.2.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-WCAG20-20081211/#consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change).

So it can be conforming to have no submit button, for example when

> the user has been advised of the behavior before using the component

Related technique: [G13: Describing what will happen before a change to a form control that causes a change of context to occur is made](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20130905/G13)

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to note here is that a change of *content* **does not** immediately mean a change of *context*.

From a [3.2.2 guideline](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html) perspective, your select box is highly likely to be perfectly fine.

A change of context means a *really drastic* change. Something like when the user selects an option in the select box, focus is shifted to a different section of the page. Also things like causing a full page refresh or opening a new tab will also fail this criterion.

> ### [WCAG "change of context" definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html#context-changedef)
>
> major changes in the content of the Web page that, if made without user awareness, can disorient users who are not able to view the entire page simultaneously
>
> Changes in context include changes of:
>
> - user agent;
> - viewport;
> - focus;
> - content that changes the meaning of the Web page.
>
> **Note:** A change of content is not always a change of context. Changes in content, such as an expanding outline, dynamic menu, or a tab control do not necessarily change the context, unless they also change one of the above (e.g., focus).
>
> **Example:** Opening a new window, moving focus to a different component, going to a new page (including anything that would look to a user as if they had moved to a new page) or significantly re-arranging the content of a page are examples of changes of context.

So if all you are doing is modifying some content elsewhere on the page and not messing around with the users focus point, you are doing everything just fine from a 3.2.2 guideline perspective.

### You are currently failing in another way though

There is one thing that is causing your select box to fail accessibility. It is lacking a label. This is a fail against guideline [2.4.6 Headings and Labels](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/navigation-mechanisms-descriptive.html). The lack of a label means that users will not know what the select box is for.

```
<form action="#">
    <label for="unique-id">Label for select box</label>
    <select id="unique-id" {... all that other junk ...}>
        {...<option> elements...}
    </select>
</form>
```