# Is it possible to make a accessible form without a submit button?

Tags: ajax, forms, accessibility

I am trying to create a site with high rankings in accessibility and one of the things i have come across is. My live search (that makes a ajax request and shows suggestions from what you type in the search bar on "keyup").

The list of suggestions i full of links that will take you to the page you are looking for meaning there is no submit page containing your results you just click the links therefore a submit button would be in my opinion redundant and useless.

My question therefore: Is it possible to make a form ex a live search without a submit button without the site being ranked lower than if it had a search button?

Comment: Its usually considered good practice to have a 'fallback' scenario. Say, for instance, the user is not using JS (god forbid) or if the user is using a screen reader of some sort - the search box should direct the user to a new page with listed results. [A helpful guide to building accessible sites](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/)

Comment: @Jackson Your comment could be the answer.

Comment: See also: [Changing form to include a submit button for WCAG](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21819437/1591669)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to make a form ex a live search without a submit button without the site being ranked lower than if it had a search button?

You have to read [WCAG Success Criterion 3.2.2 On Input](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html)

The first technique proposed is [G80: Providing a submit button to initiate a change of context](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/G80)

But there's another technique which would not require a submit button:
[G13: Describing what will happen before a change to a form control that causes a change of context to occur is made](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20161007/G13)

**TLDR: yes, but.**

Answer (score 1):

Its usually considered good practice to have a 'fallback' scenario. Say, for instance, the user is not using JS (god forbid) or if the user is using a screen reader of some sort - the search box should direct the user to a new page with listed results.

A helpful guide to building accessible sites can be found at (https://www.w3.org)[https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/]

Comment: Thank you for the help @Jackson i will start making fallback on the site, haven't even considered that scenario

Comment: Standard screenreaders use javascript. It's not an accessibility concern.